# Google Earth Plugin with LabVIEW: High CPU usage when adding placemarks

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin, labview

I'm writing an application in LabVIEW which uses the Google Earth Plugin to display events on the globe. Each event is a single point kml placemark with an icon which is a 3kb png file. Placemarks are uploaded to the plugin as they are received by the software. I am experiencing increasing CPU usage with the number of placemarks that are added.

I have tested displaying a new placemark every second and running until the software running the plugin completely froze. The GEPlugin stopped responding (i.e. the globe did not respond to the mouse) at around 1200 placemarks added and CPU usage was at ~30%. When the software itself froze the plugin was using around 50% CPU and ~3700 placemarks had been added). After the freeze, no new placemarks were added which caused the software to respond (but not the plugin) so I could clear all the placemarks. After the placemarks were cleared then the CPU usage of the plugin returned to around 5% CPU.

So what I've seen is that GEPlugin CPU usage increases linearly with each kml placemark added. Is this the expected behaviour/ a normal limitation of the plugin? If not is there a more efficient way of adding many placemarks to the globe?

I am using GEPlugin version 7.1.1.1580 (API version 1.010) and LabVIEW 12.0f3

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I was testing on a Dual-Core 2.4GHz laptop with 4GB RAM.

Comment: -1 I'd be glad to take a look, but not to guess ;) If you have a test case post it on http://jsfiddle.net/ or something and link to it, or at least post test case code here. FWIW using executeBatch from the google.earth namespace can reduce overhead when making repeated calls to the api.

Comment: @Fraser Thanks - LabVIEW is a graphical language, and the GEPlugin is embedded in an ActiveX container (which also limits the methods and properties in the API that are exposed to me) so unfortunately I don't have any code that I can post here or on jsfiddle. I'd be happy to link to a LabVIEW demo project which shows the behaviour - or build an .exe that shows the same if that would help?

Comment: It sounds like like you a memory leak somewhere but without a reproducible case it is impossible to say where. It could be that you are you are holding on to something preventing it being disposed by the garbage collector, or a creating some objects you are unaware of. FWIW here is a simple example of creating and positioning 1200 placemarks in a tight loop - http://jsfiddle.net/fraser/97H5Q/1/ - runs smooth, CPU peaks at 3.2% - GEPlugin memory useage is 3.2MB through out.

Comment: @Fraser That is very illuminating, it looks to me like there are some massive discrepancies between running the plugin in a browser and in an ActiveX container (or maybe just LabVIEW specific) as the memory usage after initialisation is 117MB which then shoots up to 178 after adding a single kml file which displays a line through several coordinates and a few icons. I'll see if I can do anything to make this more reasonable and post back. Though at the moment I'm not too hopeful as my code is quite high level so there isn't much I can tweak... thanks for your help it's been very useful

Comment: I use the GEPlugin in C#/C++ a lot and have never had this issue. Is the "ActiveX container" you speak of some kind of LabVIEW object? I generally use either the IWebBrowser2 interface in c++ or the native WebBrowser control in c#. What is your "ActiveX container"? Linking to a demo would be good - to my mind it does appear to  LabVIEW/implementation issue rather than a Google Earth Plugin issue - but obviously that is just a guess.